# How to write a for loop-similar like in JSX?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to append all the array members in React to the frontend like this:

```
          <td>{this.state.personData.results[0].name.toString()}</td>
          <td>{this.state.personData.results[0].birth_year.toString()}</td>
```

How would I write a for loop that enables me to do the above, and loop through all the elements in the array?

Comment: Do you want to loop through  `result[0]`, `result[1]`, etc? Or `name`, `birth_year`, etc?

Comment: result[0], result[1] etc

Comment: `map` function is better and faster than a for loop

Answer (score 0):

Use the `array.map` function.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
{
  this.state.personData.results.map(result => (
    <td key={result.name}>{result.name.toString()}</td>
    <td>{result.birth_year.toString()}</td>
  ))
}
```